# Finding many matches to one row in the same table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

My table is this.

```
users_table:

 id | name | admin   | property_id
-----------------------------------
 1  | x    | 1       | 0
 2  | y    | 1       | 0
 3  | z    | 0       | 1
 4  | t    | 0       | 2
 4  | u    | 0       | 2
 4  | o    | 0       | 2
```

I have two `records` which are `admin` and some other `records` which belong to one of these two records by matching the `property_id` with the `id`.
In the end what I want is the `admin` row data and the `count` of its `properties`.
The problem is that the data is all in the same table. 
This is what should be the output from the desired query.

```
  id | name | admin   | property_count
-----------------------------------
  1  | x    | 1       | 1
  2  | y    | 1       | 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ad1fb/4

```
SELECT u.*, COUNT(ut.id) property_count
FROM users_table u
LEFT JOIN users_table ut
ON u.id = ut.property_id
WHERE u.admin = 1
GROUP BY u.id, u.name, u.admin
```

Comment: i would also add in a ORDER BY MySQL 8.0 does not auto sort GROUP BY annymore because Implicit sorting by GROUP BY was deprecated in MySQL.. Also this query can only be trusted when id column is PRIMARY or UNIQUE key then MySQL can correctly use functional dependency to resolve the query.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I don't see how ORDER BY is related to this post. Can you provide any link to read? or any example to explain your point please?

Comment: "Also this query can only be trusted when id column is PRIMARY or UNIQUE key then MySQL can correctly use functional dependency to resolve the query. "  One link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ad1fb/3 and the topicstarter makes it clear id column isn't unique.

Comment: @Alex I believe he means that in the case where duplicate values of `id` exist and are referenced by `property_id`, the query is going to return multiple results.  I have no idea if that's actually the desired behavior in such a situation.

Comment: "Relying on implicit GROUP BY sorting in MySQL 5.6 is deprecated. To achieve a specific sort order of grouped results, it is preferable to use an explicit ORDER BY clause. GROUP BY sorting is a MySQL extension that may change in a future release; for example, to make it possible for the optimizer to order groupings in whatever manner it deems most efficient and to avoid the sorting overhead. " source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-nutshell.html

Comment: @RaymondNijland I still see no relation to ORDER BY http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ad1fb/4 OP did not ask for any order or sort.

Comment: And here? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/48WiLrLReeCUUqF3jo17Tg/0 vs https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/48WiLrLReeCUUqF3jo17Tg/1   one is auto sorting the `GROUP BY` the other is not.

Comment: @JamesK I can understand some ambiguous returns with my not full GROUP BY but I can't see how that is related to ORDER BY mentioned by Raymond

Comment: @RaymondNijland did OP mention that he needs some specific order? Why do you care about order that much?

Comment: "did OP mentioned that he needs some specific order? Why do you care about order that much? " Well "This is what should be the output from the desired query." he kinda said the order

Comment: @RaymondNijland that is how you see it. I see that differently. I don't see any order requirements in OP. And from my point of view, I prefer not to add any extra order to any query because of extra work required on MySQL side which means lower performance. So untill order IS the requirement I would never recommend to add any ORDER.

Comment: "that is how you see it. I see that differently." true thats your right.. iäm only adding the information about " implicit GROUP BY "  for futher readers so they can understand why the GROUP BY isn't ordering annymore when they come on this page by anny chance... "I prefer not to add any extra order to any query because of extra work required on MySQL side which means lower performance. So untill order IS the requirement I would never recommend to add any ORDER." You can disable Implicit `GROUP BY` sorting with `ORDER BY NULL` in MySQL by the way.

Comment: @Alex and all the others who helped me , sorry for my delay. The ID field is unique and the solution Alex gave worked  Gordon's solution is the same and works also. When I take out the GROUP BY , it stops working and returns just one single record.

Comment: @Alex, one little question if you have still time. I've tried to get the results and use the same query to join to another table but it seems that when WHERE is in the query, you can't LEFT JOIN more than one time.

Comment: You can. Just set another post on SO and share what exactly do you want to achieve.

Comment: @Alex I just posted another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51484612/finding-many-matches-to-one-row-in-the-same-table-and-getting-results-from-a-sec

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want a self-join and aggregation:

```
select t1a.id, t1a.name, t1a.admin, count(t1.id) as property_count
from table1 t1a left join
     table1 t1
     on t1a.id = t1.property_id
where t1a.admin = 1
group by t1a.id, t1a.name, t1a.admin;
```

There is, incidentally, a trickier way to do this without a `join`:

```
select (case when admin = 1 then id else property_id end) as id,
       max(case when admin = 1 then name end) as name,
       max(admin) as admin,
       sum( admin <> 1 ) as property_count
from table1 t1
group by (case when admin = 1 then id else property_id end);
```

Comment: i would also add in a `ORDER BY` MySQL 8.0 does not auto sort GROUP BY annymore because Implicit sorting by GROUP BY was deprecated in MySQL..