# Finding many matches to one row in the same table and getting results from a second table based on the results

Tags: mysql, sql

I know that the question title may not be quit clear to understand but I try to explain:

```
users_table:

id | name | admin   | property_id
-----------------------------------
 1  | x    | 1       | 0
 2  | y    | 1       | 0
 3  | z    | 0       | 1
 5  | t    | 0       | 2
 6  | u    | 0       | 2
 7  | o    | 0       | 2
```

`users_table` has two or more records which are `admin` and some other records which belong to one of these `admin` records by matching the `property_id` with the `id`. In the end what I want is the `admin` row data and the `count` of its `properties`. This is what should be the output from the first part of the query:

```
  id | name | admin   | property_count
-----------------------------------
  1  | x    | 1       | 1
  2  | y    | 1       | 3
```

Until now I know how to get the desired results but here begins the problem.I have another table

```
sells_table:

id | seller_id | sell_amount
----------------------------
 1 | 3         | 250
 2 | 5         | 120
 3 | 7         | 100
 4 | 5         | 200
```

So this is the logic: every `admin` has many `properties` and each `property` has many `sells`.
I want all records for each `admin` from the `users_table` plus the count of its `property_id`. 
And then query the `sells_table` in a way where for each `property` of each `admin` the number of `sells` and the `sum` of the total sells gets calculated.
 for example this should be the result for the `admin` with the `id 2` and the `name y`:

```
  name | properties | property_sells | property_amount
  --------------------------------------------------------
   y   |    3       |     3          |   420
```

`y` has `3 properties`. Property with `id 5` which belongs to `y(admin)` has `two` `sells` and `id 7` which also belongs to `y(admin)` has `one` sell and the `sum` of these `3 sells is 420`.

Comment: i believe i've seen this same question and the same answers before today.. Do i have a déjà vu??

Comment: @RaymondNijland no it isn't the same. You're right, I posted another question a few hours ago but this one is more complicated. You can have a look at my last question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51480531/finding-many-matches-to-one-row-in-the-same-table-in-mysql. Would be great if you'd have a look before DVing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
select ua.id, ua.name, ua.admin, count(distinct u.id) as property_count,
       sum(s.sell_amount) as amount
from users_table ua left join
     users_table u
     on ua.id = u.property_id left join
     sales s
     on s.seller_id = u.id
where ua.admin = 1
group by ua.id, ua.name, ua.admin;
```

Comment: can you give me the fiddle link please ? so I can see how it works

Comment: @Strawberry I asked him politely if he can or not because I'm not at my laptop now and it was urgent. At least he tried to help and I will check it myself for sure and approve the answer. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36834d/2

```
SELECT u.id, U.name, u.admin, COUNT(DISTINCT ut.id) property_count, SUM(st.sell_amount)
FROM users_table u
LEFT JOIN users_table ut
ON u.id = ut.property_id
LEFT JOIN sells_table st
ON ut.id  = st.seller_id
WHERE u.admin = 1
GROUP BY u.id, u.admin, u.name
```

Comment: thanks a lot you're the champ ;). I gave Gordon the credit for the right answer even though you both had the same right solution but since I approved your answer in the question before I gave it to him. Thanks again.